# query mysql database from inside a class using properties

Tags: php, mysql, database, class, oop

Hi this is kind of an upgraded version of this question:
[query mysql database from inside a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983906/query-mysql-database-from-inside-a-class)
The difference from the previous question, is i need a dynamic query not a static one or l$query = "SELECT col_1 FROM db.table";  So in order to have a dynamic query i need to use properties (or variables) so i can call different tables from that same class, or something like this "SELECT ‘$data’ FROM ‘$table’ ";

So far my class looks like this, similar to the previous question:

```
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "intranetpugle");

class crudmum {

    private $table;
    private $data;
    private $mysqli;

  function __construct($mysqli) {   
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
  }


function runQuery($data2, $table2)
  {
    $this->table = $table2; $this->data = $data2;
    $query = "SELECT '$this->data' FROM '$this->table' ";

    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($r);

    while($stmt->fetch())
    {    
          echo "<option>" . $r . "</option>";
    } 
  } 
};
```

This is how i run it:

```
$showme = new crudmum($mysqli); 
$showme->runQuery("priority", "trackboards" );
```

**Note:**  When i dont use variables or properties inside the query or somethng like this, SELECT priority FROM trackboards, the query  does work, only when i input the properties or variables (like the given example) it does not work.

I get this error:
**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in **C:\xampp\htdocs\devserv\i+d\bootstrap\functions.php** on line **76**

Anyone see what am i doing wrong, of course  there is a mistake with the database query any ideas on how to query the database right in a dynamic way within a class, sorry new with OOP with PHP!

Comment: Can you echo your query "$query = "SELECT '$this->data' FROM '$this->table' ";" and exit the code so that we can check what is the issue.

Comment: Replace your select with the literal query  `SELECT priority FROM trackboards` and see if it works. If it does, then there's something wrong with your properties.

Comment: Hi, SELECT priority FROM trackboards does work, only when i input the properties or variables it does not work

Comment: Are these separate files or one file?

Comment: Doesn't marke sense when using parameters the fatal error gets resolved and runQuery function returns some results. The `Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object` explicitly states that `$this->mysqli` is not a _mysqli database resource_. Checking with a literal query should make absolutely no difference occording to your supplied error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the mistake which was to add 'quotes' on the variables, like shown below:

```
 $query = "SELECT '$this->data' FROM '$this->table' ";
```

The correct way would be to take out those 'quotes' on the variables or like this:

```
$query = "SELECT $this->data FROM $this->table ";
```

With that fix, the query runs just fine, guess i lacked attention to detail, thanx everyone for their help.